# Rake Task: error handling

Tags: ruby, rake

I am still learning Rake.

Does Rake has built in support to handle task's error like MSBuild of NANT: if this task failed; execute anoter tasks (rolling back, etc.)

e.g.: in MSBuild they have `OnError` element

```
<OnError ExecuteTargets="RollBackDatabase" />
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found out the answer:

just use normal exception handling block

```
task :will_fail_task do
  begin
    raise "something's wrong here"
  rescue
    rollback()
    raise "error executing task"
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this a bit more generically? So we can have a :failed task that gets run if any other task fails.

Comment: just an idea, I would create a task with try catch block; inside the try block I would execute/call/invoke all the smaller tasks. Just remember to reenable before invoking task(if needed)